# Is the distinction between might vs could possible in French?

Tags: verbes

"Could" seems to talk about ability:

> I **could** take all of next week off from work. (I have enough
>   vacation days left).

Here, I have the ability to take the next week off. There is no suggestion that I think that I want to, or that I intend to. Perhaps I'm merely laying out my options, before I decide if I want to do it or not.

In contrast, "might" seems to talk about possibility:

> It might rain tomorrow

and if the subject is human, it talks of intention:

> I **might** take all of next week off from work.

Here, I'm not just saying that I'm *able* to take the next week off, but that I have some intention of actually doing it (but that I'm not 100% sure that I actually want to or not).

But in French, according to [this website](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/modal-verbs/), both "could" and "might" are translated by using the verb "pouvoir".

Question:
1. Is this distinction between "could" and "might" possible to communicate, in French?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "might" with the sense of intention, as in you're considering it, I think there are a lot of options:

> Je pourrais peut-être poser la semaine prochaine.
>
> Peut-être que j'aimerais poser la semaine prochaine.
>
> Je considère poser la semaine prochaine.
>
> Je crois peut-être poser la semaine prochaine.
>
> Peut-être que je poserai la semaine prochaine.
>
> Et si je pose la semaine prochaine.

For "could" as in you would be able to if you wanted, it's a little more limited:

> Je pourrais poser la semaine prochaine.
>
> Je serais libre de poser la semaine semaine.

I'm sure there are more minor variations for both, and no doubt some overlap as there is in English.

Answer (score 1):

I think

> I could take all of next week off from work. (I have enough vacation days left).

could be translated to "Je pourrais...". And

> I might take all of next week off from work.

could be translated to "Je pourrais peut être...". But I don't think a one word translation exists in French to differentiate "could" and "might".

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, "Je pourrais..." (without the peut être) would always be understood as "I could.." and never "I might.."?

Comment: It really depends on the context but in most cases yes

Comment: Agreed, no one-word match. Je pourrais seems great for could (or je peux) but might seems to engender more variation. Je devrais, peut-être que je vais, je considère

Comment: @LukeSawczak: what do you mean by "might seems to endenger more variation"? Are you saying that "Je pourrais" gives a rise in feeling, in whoever hears the question, that .. there is some kind of variation meant.. or .. something?

Comment: @silph I meant that *could* ~ *pourrais* seems like a good, close match, but that *might* has many more possible translations, at least in this context.

Comment: @LukeSawczak could you consider writing an answer to discuss the different ways a person might translate "might"?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, `I could` is like "I can, if I want it" but `I might` is "I can, and I kinda want it".

As a french native, to translate `I could take all of next week off from work. (I have enough vacation days left).` I would say :

> Je peux poser la semaine prochaine. (Il me reste assez de jours de congés)

This sentence indicates that I can, but that's it.

But, to translate `I might take all of next week off from work.` I would use conditional :

> Je pourrais poser la semaine prochaine.

This sentence indicates that I am hesitating or at least thinking about it.